# данный ключ отсутствует в словаре

Tags: c#, winforms

Выдает ошибку "данный ключ отсутствует в словаре" при нажатии на Q,W... работают только клавиши от D1 до D0 и backsapace.
Вопрос: почему выдает ошибку, вроде же верно все?

```
public enum Notes
{
    Do1, Re1, Mi1, Fa1, Col1, La1, Si1,
    Do2, Re2, Mi2, Fa2, Col2, La2, Si2,
    Do3, Re3, Mi3, Fa3, Col3, La3, Si3,
    Do4, Re4, Mi4, Fa4, Col4, La4, Si4,
    Do5, Re5, Mi5, Fa5, Col5, La5, Si5, Do6,
    DoSharp1, ReSharp1, FaSharp1, ColSharp1, LaSharp1,
    DoSharp2, ReSharp2, FaSharp2, ColSharp2, LaSharp2,
    DoSharp3, ReSharp3, FaSharp3, ColSharp3, LaSharp3,
    DoSharp4, ReSharp4, FaSharp4, ColSharp4, LaSharp4,
    DoSharp5, ReSharp5, FaSharp5, ColSharp5, LaSharp5
}

private Dictionary<Notes, MediaPlayer> sounds = new Dictionary<Notes, MediaPlayer>();

private Dictionary<Keys, bool> pressStates = new Dictionary<Keys, bool>();

private Dictionary<Keys, Notes> KeySounds = new Dictionary<Keys, Notes>
{
    { Keys.D1, Notes.Do1 },
    ....
    //для каждой ноты перечисления Notes задаем клавишу клавиатуры
    ....
    { Keys.NumPad9, Notes.LaSharp5 }
};

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Инициализируем словари
    foreach (Notes s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Notes)).Cast<Notes>())
    {
        sounds.Add(s, new MediaPlayer());
        pressStates.Add((Keys)s, false);
    }
    //Наполняем словарь звуками
    sounds[Notes.Do1].Open(new Uri("s//_1.wav", UriKind.Relative));
    ....
    //Для каждой ноты задаем звуковой файл
    ....
    sounds[Notes.LaSharp5].Open(new Uri("s//25.wav", UriKind.Relative));
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{       
    if (!KeySounds.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode)) return;
    if (!pressStates[e.KeyCode])
    {
        pressStates[e.KeyCode] = true;
        PlaySound(KeySounds[e.KeyCode]);
    }  
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{        
    if (!KeySounds.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode)) return;
    if (pressStates[e.KeyCode])
    {
        pressStates[e.KeyCode] = false;
        StopSound(KeySounds[e.KeyCode]);
    }             
}
```

Comment: Ну, а вы посмотрите, о каком ключе идёт речь. И есть ли он реально в словаре.

Comment: что есть тип `Keys`? и как он соотносится с типом `Notes`?

Comment: @Igor Keys - это стандартное перечисление WinForms https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor keys это клавиши клавиатуры, по идее к клавише привязан звук ноты

Comment: Все просто, вы неправильно инициализируете словарь `pressStates`. Его нужно инициализировать в отдельном от `sounds` цикле, потому что сейчас у вас в него попадают неправильные ключи, но при этом приведение происходит правильно и компилятор об этом ни чего вам не говорит.

Comment: @Valentin А вы не можете всё-таки как-то упросить ваш код, чтобы было проще воспринимать? А также отформатировать.

Comment: Так вроде получше смотрится. лишнего нет и идея сохранена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
//Инициализируем словари
foreach (Notes s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Notes)).Cast<Notes>())
{
    sounds.Add(s, new MediaPlayer());
    pressStates.Add((Keys)s, false);
}
```

Значения из перечисления `Notes` могут быть приведены к значениям `Keys`, потому что оба перечисления основаны на типе `int`. Компилятор считает что вы понимаете что делаете, раз используете явное приведение и оно может быть выполнено без ошибок. Однако это ни коим образом не гарантирует, что числовые коды ваших нот будут совпадать с кодами клавиш. которые вы хотите использовать.

Для исправления, разделите на два независимых цикла, например так:

```
//Инициализируем словарь нот
foreach (Notes s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Notes)).Cast<Notes>())
{
    sounds.Add(s, new MediaPlayer());
}
//Инициализируем словарь состояний клавиш
foreach (Keys k in KeySounds.Keys)
{
    pressStates.Add(k, false);
}
```

или можно даже в одном цикле, но тогда вот так:

```
//Инициализируем словари
foreach (var s in KeySounds)
{
    sounds.Add(s.Key, new MediaPlayer());
    pressStates.Add(s.Value, false);
}
```

Comment: @Valentin я рад что помог. Но все таки, в следующий раз постарайтесь самостоятельно ужать код до читаемого размера, оставив только нужное. Это был довольно простой случай и в глаза бросился со второго прочтения. в более сложном случае, в такой простыне будет невозможно разобраться

Comment: хорошо, учту на будущее :)